# How do I apply css to an element only if it has certain text content in it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, element

http://jsfiddle.net/aWp2g/2/

css

```
.highlight {
    color: yellow;
}
```

html

```
<div>fox</div>
<div>brown</div>
```

jQuery

```
if ($('div').text() == 'fox') {
    this.addClass('highlight');
}
```

My above code is not working, I want it to add a class to the element containing a certain text so that it applies a highlighting css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aWp2g/13/ updated my using you guys' suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your code refers to `window` object.
`.text()` method returns text content of all the selected elements, the returned value is: `foxbrown` which is not equal to `fox`.

You can use `:contains` selector for selecting elements that *contain* a specific text:

```
$('div:contains(fox)').addClass('highlight');
```

Exact match:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return (this.textContent || this.innerText) === 'fox';
}).addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 2):

As @undefined mentioned

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return (this.textContent || this.innerText) === 'fox';
}).addClass('highlight');
```

Should work ok -- But also remember to have your jsfiddle include jquery or else it will not run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try :empty selector. It won't help you with the certain text but with text existence.