# Javascript/jQuery to apply CSS to element containing specific text/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply CSS to HTML elements that have specific HTML within them using Javascript/jQuery.  What I've got is basically:

```
<ol>
<li>*<a href=http://foo.com/1>A bunch of text</a>
<li><a href=http://foo.com/2>More text</a>
<li>*<a href=http://foo.com/3>Even more text</a>
<li><a href=http://foo.com/4>Just a little more text</a>
</ol>
```

What I want is to run `.addClass()` on the two `<li>` tags that are followed by an asterisk.

I know I could use `$("ol li:contains(*)")` but there could be asterisks in the link text, so I can't trust that to be 100% accurate.  Ideally, I'd like to find a way to run `.addClass()` on all `<li>` tags that are followed by `*<a href=http://foo.com/`, but just a way to run it on `<li>` followed by `*` would probably do it.

I looked at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623057/how-do-i-apply-css-to-an-element-only-if-it-has-certain-text-content-in-it-using), but it doesn't help, even if I switched out `innerText` for `innerHTML`, because I'm not looking to match the whole HTML of the `<li>`, just the beginning.

Comment: You are missing the closing `</li>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("ol li").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().charAt(0) === '*';
}).addClass('awesome');
```